# Appropriate Use of Supercolum in Schema

Tags: cassandra

I need to track versions of data in Cassandra.  I was thinking that the Version # would be a super column, the entity id would be the row id and then the columns I need to track would be the columns. So, for example, version 1 of entity would be:

- supercolumn: v1
- rowid: UUID
- columns: timestamp, requestid, userid, state, data, etc...

When querying, the most common request will be

- give me version X for record y
- give me the version X - 1 and X + 1
  for record y.

Of lesser importance, would be queries such as:

- give me all rows that are in state 1.
- give me all records changed by userid x.
- give me all rows where timestamp is between x and y.

So is the above approach with supercolumns the best approach or is there a better schema to  accomplish the above.  Are there caveats to using/querying supercolumns that I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, do not use supercolumns.  They are effectively deprecated and have many drawbacks.  In your model you can easily replace your supercolumns with composites by using a composite key with two components, the first being your UUID and the second being your version.  All your queries will be supported by this model.  [Check this out](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introduction-to-composite-columns-part-1) for more information on composites.

Comment: Wow, am I glad I asked the question.  I had already gone ahead and coded as I described.  So are composites essentially the rowid (my rowid becomes UUID:version)?  Or are composites the "column name" and each of my columns would become, for example, requestid:version, userid:version, state:version, data:version, etc.?

Comment: You can have composite keys or columns.  In your case a composite key with UUID:version seems to satisfy your use case.